# starling framework - how to draw cirlcles

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop, starling-framework

i was able to integrate starling in my flashdevelop enviroment and Im able to create quads with the built in Quad class.

Now I need to create circles.

How do I create circles with code?

Mirza

Comment: Graphics extension mentioned below is good, but depending on your situation, you can also use old school shape drawing API to produce a shape, render it to a bitmap, and then use that as a texture for Starling. Not a good idea if you need to redraw the graphics often, though.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that Starling doesn't have a Drawing API by default, but you can check out this drawing API :

https://github.com/StarlingGraphics/Starling-Extension-Graphics

There are likely other extensions to add the same functionality.

Edit : -- Please also see the first comment by @jpop under the question as if you don't need to redraw the graphics often, it's an excellent solution that doesn't require the extension.

Answer (score 0):

There is now the `starling.display.Canvas` class which provides support for basic vector drawing, including circles.